# Xephyr with two screens overlaps the screens

Tags: x11, xorg

I use Xephyr to develop a window manager.

I start Xephyr like this:

```bash
Xephyr +xinerama +extension RANDR -screen 800x600 -screen 800x600 -ac :1
```

I expect `xrandr` to show me both virtual screens, instead I get:

```
$ DISPLAY=:1 xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 160 x 160, current 1600 x 600, maximum 1600 x 1200
default connected 800x600+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1600x1200      0.00  
   1400x1050      0.00  
   1280x960       0.00  
   1280x1024      0.00  
   1152x864       0.00  
   1024x768       0.00  
   832x624        0.00  
   800x600        0.00* 
   720x400        0.00  
   480x640        0.00  
   640x480        0.00  
   640x400        0.00  
   320x240        0.00  
   240x320        0.00  
   160x160        0.00
```

`current` of 1600 x 600 makes sense, I suppose.
But only one screen is detected.

Calling `XineramaQueryScreens(dpy, &nn);` from my application gives the two screens overlapping. They are both there, with the right dimensions, but both at (0, 0).

What is the correct way to create two virtual screens side by side using Xephyr?

Answer (score 0):

[This conversation](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=918457) implies that randr and Xinerama aren't quite compatible. This surprises me, because I do use both when I run my usual WM, and because `Xephyr` allows to enable the extension.

Starting Xephyr like this kind of works:

```
Xephyr +xinerama +extension RANDR -screen 800x600+0+0 -screen 800x600+800+0 -ac :1
```

(note the position in the screen geometries)

`xrandr` still fails to report both screens, but my C application calling to `XineramaQueryScreens(dpy, &new_num_mons);` gets the correct information.